# Prove that $|\int_a^b \sin \phi(t) dt| \leq \frac {4}{m}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $\phi~''$ is continuous and nonzero on $[a,b]$ and if there is a constant $m>0$ such that $\phi~'(t) \geq m ~\forall~t \in [a,b]$. Prove that $|\int_a^b \sin \phi(t) ~dt| \leq \dfrac {4}{m}$

**Attempt:** $I = \int_a^b \sin \phi(t)~ dt $

Let $ \phi(t) =u \implies \phi'(t)~dt = du$

Hence, $I = \int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} \dfrac {\sin u} {u'} du$.

**EDIT**: I was trying to apply the second mean value theorem for integrals. But, for that, though $\sin$ is continuous in any interval, however, $d(\dfrac {1}{u′})=\dfrac{−u''}{u~′~^2} $, though continuous but may not possess the same sign in the given interval. So, can we still apply the second mean value theorem?

How do I move ahead? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this an exercise from Apostol's book?

Comment: yeah, Calculus Volume $1$ by Apostol

Comment: Are you sure you correctly applied the substitution? You're not very far from solving it, you have to exploit $\phi'(t)\geq m$ and the mean value theorem.

Comment: Thanks, i just corrected it.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I was trying to apply the second mean value theorem. But, for that, though $\sin$ is continuous in any interval, however, $d ( \dfrac {1}{u'} ) = \dfrac {- u~''}{{u'}^2}$ , though continuous but may not possess the same sign in the given interval. So, can we still apply the second mean value theorem?

Comment: okay, got it. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left|\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{\sin{(\phi(t))}d(\phi(t))}{\phi'(t)}\right|\le \dfrac{|\cos{\phi{(b)}}-\cos{\phi(a)}|}{m}\le\dfrac{2}{m}$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain what was the use of the condition - $\phi~''$ is continuous and nonzero on $[a,b]$

Comment: (+1) Also see the "Second mean value theorem for integration" on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: Sorry but I still can't understand the use of the condition - 
ϕ '′ is continuous and nonzero on [a,b]. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

$\int_a^b \sin [ \phi (x) ] dx = \int_a^b \{\sin [ \phi (x) ] \phi'(x)\} 
\frac{1}{ \phi'(x) } dx$

We may apply Theorem 5.5 of Apostol's Calculus Volume 1, with $g(x) = \sin [ \phi (x) ] \phi'(x)$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{ \phi'(x) }$

Since $\phi''(x)$ is continuous and non-zero it cannot change sign by Bolzano's Theorem (Theorem 3.6 in Apostol's Calculus Volume 1). So $f'(x)  = -\frac{\phi''(x)}{\{\phi'(x)\}^2}$ always has the opposite sign as $\phi''(x)$!

The required integral then becomes:

$\frac{1}{\phi'(a)} \int_a^c \sin [ \phi (x) ] \phi'(x) dx + \frac{1}{\phi'(b)} \int_c^b \sin [ \phi (x) ] \phi'(x) dx
= \frac{1}{\phi'(a)} \{ \cos(\phi(c)) - \cos(\phi(a)) \} + \frac{1}{\phi'(b)} \{ \cos(\phi(b)) - \cos(\phi(c)) \}$

In view of the fact that $|\cos(x) - \cos(y)| \le 2$ for all values of $x$ and $y$, we have:

$|\int_a^b \sin [ \phi (x) ] dx| \le \frac{4}{m}$.

This completes the proof.